# Code for reading input from multiple analog pins on Arduino will not show values

Tags: c++, arduino

This code that I tried to build myself does not give the output I want.
I'm hoping for an output lik "125, 567, 654, 332, 222, 123".
(6 values, separated by ", ")

If I run another program, I get the values, so there is someting wrong or missing in my code for sure.

```
#define cellPin A0
#define cellPin A1
#define cellPin A2
#define cellPin A3
#define cellPin A4
#define cellPin A5

float counts = 0;
float const pins = 6;    // No of pins from 0 to 5

int timer = 1000;

int stored_pin_values[5];
int average_reads = 20;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);           //  setup serial
}

void loop() {

  for (int x = 0; x < pins; x++) {              // counter for each pin, from 0 to 5

    for (int i = 0; i < average_reads; i++) {          // counter for each reading of the selected pin
      if (i == 0) { analogRead("cellPin A"[i]); }                      // Read pin but do not use first reading
      if (i != 0) { counts = analogRead("cellPin A"[i]) + counts; }   // read the input pin and add to sum of counts
    }
    stored_pin_values[x] = counts / (average_reads - 1);              // Calc. average of pin. -1 cus we did not use the first reading
    counts = 0;
  }

  for (int y = 0; y < pins; y++) {              // Counter for printing average value of each pin
    if (y == pins - 1) { Serial.println(stored_pin_values[y]); }    //on last pos. print "ln"
    else {
      Serial.print(stored_pin_values[y]);                          // print "average pinvalue" separated by ", "
      Serial.print(", ");
    }
  }
  delay(timer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have defined multiple values for `cellPin`.
`#define cellPin A0`
`#define cellPin A1`
`#define cellPin A2`
`#define cellPin A3`
`#define cellPin A4`
`#define cellPin A5`

I suggest to use a various name like `#define cellPin0 A0` `#define cellPin1 A1` ...
For second you call `analogRead("cellPin A"[i])`, passing string with illegal operator for argument: the right method is `analogRead(int) -> int`.

I write a little sketch for inspiring you:

```
int analogPins[6]={A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5}, //pins
     analogValues[6]={0,0,0,0,0,0}; //stores the value of analog read

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600); //serial communication with baud rate of 9600b/s
}


void loop(){
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
         analogValues[i]=analogRead(analogPins[i]);
    }
}
```

I hope that can help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I did not see that... Added working code as answer also.

Answer (score 0):

Working code after change (note: changed to 5 pin reading instead of 6):

```
int analogPins[5]={A0,A1,A2,A3,A4}, //pins
     analogValues[5]={0,0,0,0,0}; //stores the value of analog read

float counts = 0;
float const pins = 5;    // No of pins from 0 to 4

int timer = 1000;

int stored_pin_values[5];
int average_reads = 100;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);           //  setup serial
}

void loop() {

  for (int x = 0; x < pins; x++) {              // counter for each pin, from 0 to 4

    for (int i = 0; i < average_reads; i++) {          // counter for each reading of the selected pin
      if (i == 0) { analogRead(analogPins[i]); }                      // Read pin but do not use first reading
      if (i != 0) { counts = analogRead(analogPins[i]) + counts; }   // read the input pin and add to sum of counts
    }
    stored_pin_values[x] = counts / (average_reads - 1);              // Calc. average of pin. -1 cus we did not use the first reading
    counts = 0;
  }

  for (int y = 0; y < pins; y++) {              // Counter for printing average value of each pin
    if (y == pins - 1) { Serial.println(stored_pin_values[y]); }    //on last pos. print "ln"
    else {
      Serial.print(stored_pin_values[y]);                          // print "average pinvalue" separated by ", "
      Serial.print(", ");
    }
  }
  delay(timer);
}
```